# Can I call an CSS id inside another id?

Tags: css

I was wondering if I could do this in css:

```
#ItemA{
color: black
}

#ItemA: hover{
       #ItemB{
       color: orange;
}}
```

the reason is because I want multiple items to change color when hovering over another item. I´ve tried to do that, but it didnt work.

Comment: You better use `class` for the same

Comment: maybe it's time to learn some SASS/LESS

Comment: `#ItemA:hover #ItemB {}`?

Comment: @Abinthaha `#ItemA: hover .class1 #ItemB{ color: orange;}` Like this?

Comment: Yes, because giving the same Id to more than one element is not a best practice. And the method you asked in question is possible using SCSS.
https://sass-lang.com/guide
Check nesting

Comment: @Abinthaha Thanks for your time! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Do as below: (or use sass file)

```css
#ItemA {
  color: black
}

#ItemA:hover #ItemB {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="ItemA">A
  <div id="ItemB">B</div>
</div>
```